# "A user access token is required to request this resource" while trying to get user checkins in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a Facebook app, and have asked for user_checkin permission when my users click on Facebook Connect button. All well so far.

When I get a new application access token, and try to issue an FQL in order to get the users checkins however, I get the error "A user access token is required to request this resource".

What I am trying to achieve is fetch users checkins every few minutes, and from the coords information send them an email with nearby points of interest.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your applications asking for the correct extended permission to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When I get a new **application** access token,"

For that action, you will need to use the **user** access token.  You may also consider asking for offline_access permission too.

Comment: I see what you did there. So how do I get a user access token? I know from the documentation how to get an application access token (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). What is the procedure for the user access token programmatically (from a console app)?

Comment: On that long page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/, there's examples of server-side as well as client-sice getting of the USER access token.

Answer (score 0):

user_checkins no longer seems to work. It appears to have been rolled into user_status, and Facebook haven't told us. Took 15 minutes of trial and error on the graph API explorer to figure that one out.